# Hide or show different changes based on a selection in the woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to show or hide custom fields, depending on the selection made by the customer at checkout. For example, if in the "membership category" field you select "I am a company" they must compile data such as: "Company name", "company address", "Company number", "Company email".

These fields must be visible both in the order summary email and in the order administration page. I found this code that does what I want, but after selection it shows only one custom field, instead I have to show more.

```php
// Add fields
function action_woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form( $checkout ) {
    // Add select field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'referrence', array(
        'type'          => 'select', // text, textarea, select, radio, checkbox, password, about custom validation a little later
        'required'      => true, 
        'class'         => array( 'my-field', 'form-row-wide' ), // array only, read more about classes and styling in the previous step
        'label'         => 'From where you hear about us',
        'label_class'   => 'my-label',
        'options'       => array( // options for <select> or <input type="radio" />
            ''                 => 'Please select', // empty values means that field is not selected
            'Google'           => 'Google', // 'value' => 'Name'
            'LinkedIn'         => 'LinkedIn',
            'Facebook'         => 'Facebook',
            'Email'            => 'Email',
            'Referral Program' => 'Referral Program',
            'Other'            => 'Other'
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'referrence' ) );
    
    // Add textfield
    woocommerce_form_field( 'referralname', array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'class' => array( 'my-field form-row-wide' ),
        'label' => ' Referral Name',
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'referralname' ) );

    // jQuery show/hide custom textfield
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Hide textfield by default
        $( '#referralname_field' ).hide();

        // On change
        $( 'select#referrence' ).change( function() {
            if ( $( 'select#referrence' ).val() == 'Referral Program' ) {
                $( '#referralname_field' ).show();
            } else {
                $( '#referralname_field' ).hide();              
            }
        });
      
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'action_woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 10, 1 );

// Validate select field
function action_woocommerce_checkout_process() {
    // Isset    
    if ( isset( $_POST['referrence'] ) ) {
        $domain = 'woocommerce';
        $referrence = $_POST['referrence'];
        
        // Empty
        if ( empty ( $referrence ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select from where you hear about us', $domain ), 'error' );
        }
        
        // NOT empty but value is 'Please select'
        if ( ! empty ( $referrence ) && $referrence == 'Please select' ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select from where you hear about us', $domain ), 'error' );
        }       
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_process', 10, 0 );

// Save fields
function action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    // Isset    
    if ( isset( $_POST['referrence'] ) ) {
        $referrence = $_POST['referrence'];
    
        // Update meta data
        $order->update_meta_data( 'referrence', sanitize_text_field( $referrence ) );
    }
    
    // Isset    
    if ( isset( $_POST['referralname'] ) ) {
        $referralname = $_POST['referralname'];
    
        // Update meta data
        $order->update_meta_data( 'referralname', sanitize_text_field( $referralname ) );
    }   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: First, your question is unclear and incomplete. Also, you can not peak some existing code and ask others to make it for you. You need to code it yourself and ask here when you have an issue with your code. There are a lot of existing working answers related to conditional checkout fields, that will be shown or hidden depending on the customer choice. Here are [my related answers for example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+%5Bjquery%5D%5Bcheckout%5D+show). So please always better search before, and try to be more explicit and careful when asking.